# Multi-threaded Matrix initializing in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, optimization, matrix

Currently using JAMA matrix.

my program currently initializes a LOT of small matrixs (20x20 tops in size) and then does some small calculations and reads the results.

about 80% of the run time is being spent reading and initializing the matrixs and I was wondering if there is a way I can do this multi-threaded for increased speeds. (I know that there are things like OjAlgo that are great for multi-thraded matrix manipulation) but all I am doing is initializing the matrix's and reading them again.

If I use another Matrix package will it initialize the matrixs with multiple threads or would the initialization still be single threaded but the algorthems done be multi-threaded?

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading "within" the matrices wont be of any benefit for such small matrices.

Switching to a library that internally uses double[] rather than double[][] could make a difference, but my guess is you should focus on how you (re)use the matrices. Maybe your program logic can be multi-threaded.

For very small matrices (2x2, 3x3, 4x4 ...) some libraries have specialised data structures and algorithms that could speed things up significantly.